# Typescript: pick union of function type

Tags: typescript, generics

```
type UnionThing<T> = T | (value:T)=>T
```

I have union type like this : one generic primitive value and one function type

```
type FnThing<T> = ~~~~~ // expect it to be (value:T)=>T
```

Now I want to pick function type only but don't know how to.
Utility Type `Pick`is for key value and I don't have key in this union type.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your expected type is not valid TypeScript.

This

```
type FnThing = (value: T) => T
```

would not compile since `T` is not declared anywhere. So we will have to either make `FnThing` generic over `T` or subsitute a type for `T`.

```
type FnThing<T> = Extract<UnionThing<T>, (args: any) => any>

type WithoutGeneric = FnThing<number>
// type WithoutGeneric = (value: number) => number
```

or

```
type FnThing2 = Extract<UnionThing<number>, (args: any) => any>
// type FnThing2 = (value: number) => number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCoAsFwOYB5UB8UAvFKlAD5QAU1AbgIYA2ArhAFyoCUJR3AUP1CQoAMTSYc%20IqQCiAD2AAnBgGNgueMglY8hADQ0GS7AGd2UBnBA9iRKyAKDh0AOoJg6JC2ABxCHAQSgiqJGI6UnAsALYARkFOAPSJUC5Q7p7efgFBIWH0zGwWUXFBtkQl8UqCzuDQ4hi6AExhCspqGloojZExVQSG1MZmFg7lltZJKVBQAHoA-EA)

Comment: Ohoo.. Actually I forgot to declare generic! The thing I want was `type FnThing<T> = Extract<UnionThing<T>, (args: any) => any>`!
But problem is that when I use `Extract` 
the result is not `(value:T)=>T`, but `((value: T) => T) | Extract<T, (value: T) => T>
`